# An entire function satisfies $f(az+b)=f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions, analytic-continuation

Here is a problem that I got stuck on while preparing for an upcoming exam:

If $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ and $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is non-constant and entire with $f(az+b)=f(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, prove that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $a^n=1$.

I proved the first part of the problem which is the same thing but with $b=0$. I proved this by breaking into the three cases of $|a|<1$, $|a|=1$ and $|a|>1$. The first and last case, I got a contradiction that $f$ is constant (by analytic continuation and Liouville theorem respectively). I am not sure however, how to do it with $b\neq 0$. I would really appreciate a hint.

Comment: @metamorphy Why not an official answer?

Comment: For what it's worth, as long as $a\neq 0$, you can combine the first and last case: if $f(az)=f(z)$, then $f(z)=f(a(z/a))=f(z/a)$, It is also worth pointing out that there is still something to prove in the case that $|a|=1$, although this argument is likely similar to your argument when $|a|<1$, as you can show that your function is constant on various circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $a\neq 1$ then $g(z):=f\big(z+b/(1-a)\big)$ satisfies $g(az)=g(z)$.